# Can we consider Clojure's STM 'functional'?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, stm, purely-functional, referential-transparency

We know that [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function):

1. Always return the same result for a given input
2. Produce no side-effects

This leads us to [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) - where *an expression can be replaced with a value without changing the behaviour of the program*.

This tells us that a program can be said to be [purely functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional) if it *excludes destructive modifications (updates) of entities in the program's running environment*.

When we look at [Software Transactional Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory), we see *a concurrency control mechanism analogous to database transactions for controlling access to shared memory in concurrent computing*. But nothing about that is particularly functional on its own.

My question is: **Can we consider Clojure's STM 'functional'?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clojure STM is intentionally not "pure functional" because it is intended to manage state, and updating state is a side-effect. This reflects Clojure's design philosophy as a language that prefers functional programming by default, but still supplies you with the tools to do useful/stateful things, in a hopefully controlled manner.

Answer (score 2):

*Can we consider Clojure's STM 'functional'?*

No. Quite the contrary. The STM is designed to be stateful, impure, referentially opaque, however you want to put it. But in a nice way, akin, as you've noted, to database transactions.

Clojure is a layered language. The STM sits on top of the core pure functions and data structures, isolating state change in a single construct - *ref*s - which it provides a vocabulary to manipulate.

---

Clojure is layered in other ways too.

- Many control structures (`and`, `when`, ... ) are layered on a few
  special forms by means of macros.
- Most of the core functions - written in Clojure - are layered on the
  minority implemented in the JVM (or other host), which is equipped
  with the `clojure.lang` package to implement them.

Answer (score 1):

Clojure STM doesn't have referential transparency as the results can be different every time depending on operations interleaving in multiple threads.